# Excel Averageifs with multiple conditions in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am looking for some help for how to tidy the second formula below in **bold**. I am looking to calculate the average 'Pupil_Score' (this is also my first try with named ranges) based on race, I am looking to combine some groups together, in this instance Race 1 and 2. I would like to keep using the Averageifs formula as it seems shorter than my current solution as seen in the first formula. Later on I will be add more conditions that will only keep making the formula longer in the current SUM/COUNT format seem impractical.

=AVERAGEIFS(Pupil_Score,Race,3)

**=(SUMIFS(Pupil_Score,Race,1)+SUMIFS(Pupil_Score,Race,2)) /   (COUNTIFS(Race,1)+COUNTIFS(Race,2))**

I am getting different results from everyone's answer, below is the data I am testing with, maybe this can help. My formula gave 99.632, then others gave a #Value error or, 99.614 or 99.493.

Race    Pupil Score
1   98.880
1   99.588
1   99.751
1   99.780
1   100.070
2   99.765
2   98.873
2   99.013
2   99.529
2   99.600
2   99.500
2   99.751
2   99.501
2   99.543
2   99.795
2   99.857
2   99.874
2   99.875
2   99.67
2   99.755
2   99.893
2   100.050

Comment: You will get `#VALUE!` error with my suggested formula if you don't confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. If you do that correctly then the answer I get from your data is `99.632`, as you suggest - see the link to sample workbook in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `AVERAGEIFS` criteria come through as `AND` conditions. You require an `OR` condition since any one row could not be both *1* and *2*.

[image]

In the above, the sum of the blue/greens is *23*, their count is *5* making the average *4.6*. The formula in E2 is either,

`=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C8)*(B2:B8=F1:G1))/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B8=F1:G1))`

... or with the colors hardcoded as,

`=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C8)*(B2:B8={"Blue","Green"}))/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B8={"Blue","Green"}))`

For your numbers, the hardcoded version would look like,

`=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C8)*(B2:B8={1, 2}))/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B8={1, 2}))`

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can keep the formula simple is if you can come up with criteria that are not mutually exclusive. For example,

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Pupil_Score,Race,">=2",Race,"<=3")
```

This works only if race numbers are adjacent.

Others have suggested array (CSE) formulas so I won't repeat that. Those formulas tend to be rather complex. If you want to keep things simple, you could try to create a filter column in your original data, like `=OR(race=1;race=3)` and use that in your ifs. You could even use those in conjunction with the race numbers, as long as the criteria are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `AVERAGE` array formula, e.g.

`=AVERAGE(IF((Race=1)+(Race=2),Pupil_Score))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The "+" effectively gives you an "OR"

You can easily add extra conditions by adding IF functions, e.g. assuming "range1" needs to be "x"

`=AVERAGE(IF((Race=1)+(Race=2),IF(range1="x",Pupil_Score)))`

See example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nonsxgltjw2qqrz/Average_example.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
=
sum( sumifs( columntoavg, criteriacolumn, {"1","2","3"}))
/
sum( countifs(  criteriacolumn, {"1","2","3"}))
```

I think this is the cleanest and most flexible way to solve this.